# MemoryError python

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, scipy

Afternoon!
I have a MemoryError during optimization

```
sp.optimize.minimize(error_func,x0=np.array([0,0]),method='L-BFGS-B',bounds=[[-100,100],[-5,5]])
```

error_func is:

```
def error_func(W=np.array([0,1])):
    const=np.ones(len(data.loc[:,'Weight'].values))
    X=data.loc[:,'Weight'].values
    Y=data.loc[:,'Height'].values
    Y.reshape(len(Y),1)
    vect=np.transpose(np.vstack([const,X]))
    if isinstance(W[0],int) or isinstance(W[0],float):
        if isinstance(W[1],int) or isinstance(W[1],float):
            W=np.array(W)
            W=np.vstack([W[0],W[1]])
            return np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(Y,np.dot(vect,W)),2))
        else:
            W[0]=np.ones(len(W[1]))*W[0]
            W[1]=np.array(W[1])
            answer=[]
            W=np.array(W)
            W=np.vstack([W[0],W[1]])
            for i in range(len(W[1])):
                answer.append(np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(Y,np.dot(vect,W)[:,i]),2)))
            return np.array(answer)
    else:
        if isinstance(W[1],int) or isinstance(W[1],float):
            W[1]=np.ones(len(W[0]))*W[1]
            W[0]=np.array(W[0])
            answer=[]
            W=np.array(W)
            W=np.vstack([W[0],W[1]])
            for i in range(len(W[0])):
                answer.append(np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(Y,np.dot(vect,W)[:,i]),2)))
            return np.array(answer)
        else:
            answer=[]
            W=np.array(W)
            W=np.vstack([W[0],W[1]])
            for i in range(len(W[1])):
                answer.append(np.sum(np.power(np.subtract(Y,np.dot(vect,W)[:,i]),2)))
            return np.array(answer)
```

What could be a problem?
Dataframe length is 25000
Are there any memory-management instruments (like calloc, malloc in C)

Comment: Can you share your error as well?

Comment: Typical error
First row: MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Last row: MemoryError: